# Is it possible to create CommandLink dialog boxes in C++ with WINAPI or GDI+?

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

[image]

That's the result I'd like to achieve. I know it is called "CommandLink" and I've been googling for a while, finding stuff only with C#, nothing with pure C++.
I was wondering if it was possible to do something like that and if yes, how...

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Yes it's possible but your request is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I realized it's actually a bad format for a question, but you'd make my day if you could address me to the right choice. Thanks!

Comment: ...and you'd make everyone's day if you put some time into improving your post.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I didn't find any code on google, some addictional few words wouldn't make it change, it's like adding water into a soup... it's pointless!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog you're looking at is the [Task Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471.aspx) that was introduced in Vista to supersede `MessageBox()` (in fact, the text in that image says as much!).

The [`TaskDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760540.aspx) function gives you the most basic functionality of the dialog, but not the functionality you are asking for.  For that, you will need [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx) instead. This function takes a [`TASKDIALOGCONFIG` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787473.aspx). The `TDF_USE_COMMAND_LINKS` flag of the `dwFlags` member does what you want.

You can also have a [Command Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742403.aspx) on its own as well; it is just a [standard `BUTTON` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775943.aspx) with the [`BS_COMMANDLINK` style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx) applied to it.  See [How to Create a Command Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298355.aspx).

Comment: I'm getting an error when linking ComCtl32.lib, it tells me "The ordinal 345 could not be located in the dynamic link library COMCTL32.dll"

Comment: I have a manifest file I copied from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756938.aspx

Comment: @Bafforasta Please keep the swearing to an absolute minimum.

Comment: @Kyll Sorry it's just that it makes me nervous code not working without any apparent reason...

Comment: Instead of adding Common Controls 6 to a manifest file, try adding a linker pragma to a scource code (.cpp) file.  Find it at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx  It starts with `#pragma comment(linker...`, but it is too big to add to this comment.  Also, you aren't using Windows XP, right?

Comment: I'll try as you suggested. Anyway, no, I'm not using Windows XP, I'm using Windows 7 Professional SP1 64 bit.